# Weird message in group chat

Tags: skype

As shown below, skype just put in a "MT 100" into my group chat.

[image]

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: [These people](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Weird-MT-100-Message-on-Skype/td-p/3933189) are puzzled too.

Comment: Thanks for the info. They have not found the root cause though.

Comment: Clearly, otherwise it would have made for an answer. :) Will look around some more.

Comment: There was a message bug in Skype which was fixed within the last 48 hours, this could be, a mediation on the server side for clients not patched, but doesn't make sense, in a group chat of 2 so never mind

Comment: This apparently got sent to me in april.